# H2 Database not found with message it's available

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

I cannot login to my H2 Database event though i see the message that the database is available.

```
DEBUG [main] [Log Context: ]  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource:134 Loaded JDBC driver: org.h2.Driver
DEBUG [main] [Log Context: ]  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource:144 Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:testdb]
INFO  [main] [Log Context: ]  o.s.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration:68 H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
```

My `application.properties` file looks like this:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

and the database not found error messsage looks like this:

[image]

I am using h2database version 2.1.214 and spring boot version 2.5.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first try to add next properties to the Data Base URL:

```
DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Example:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Comment: Wow! Looks like that worked. could you explain why?

Comment: I'd had the same problem. This properties control the DB lifecycle.
DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT mean Don't close the database when the VM exits. More details: https://www.h2database.com/html/features.html